# Gradle: replace token in index.html

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle project. I want to add versioning to my index.html from gradle.properties by replacing @version@ token. I have tried the following:

**build.properties**

```
version=1.0.12 // i want this version
projectJdk=Oracle JDK 8
```

**build.gradle**

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.*
processResources  {
    println 'here1 '
    filesMatching('static/index.html') {
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [version:  project.version])
        println 'here2' + project.version //this is printed meaning file the exists
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<span class="col-lg-offset-5">@version@</span>
```

index.html is under **src/main/resources/static**

Thanks,

Comment: Have you found a solution?? I am running onto the same problem.